# Fluid, type liquid ignores domain when inflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

Just to start off and explain things, I have two objects one is a ico-sphere which is the fluid emitter and the domain is a skull which I baked both setting and mesh. when I hit play it works fine, the skull disappears and the fluid emitter emits fine with the exception that it ignores the domain. Because domains disappear, I had duplicated the skull (see image). The skull normals are looking outward, and I notice that the small cube that appears when ever an object becomes a domain appears outside, instead of inside, is that the issue?. Thank you [image]

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the fluid simulator domain is always square. I am treating the skull as an effector now but the liquid is falling through ignoring the obstacle completely. I've checked the normals of the skull and they are all outward. My scale is set in all objects. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem with an addon that has an obstacle Inverse feature. The addon is called FLIP Fluids.